# Is it safe to stuff some insulation above my electric stove?

Tags: insulation, hood, draft, fire-safety

I have a coil-style electric stove with a "hood" above it.  The hood has a nice light fixture built in.  It also has an exhaust fan which I frankly never use.  The problem is that there is a gap where the hood meets the wall behind the stove, and there's a tremendous cold draft along that gap.  I am thinking of stuffing a strip of fiberglass batting into that gap, but I wonder if that's completely safe.  What if a bit of the batting came loose and fell and caught on fire?

How are these darned things supposed to work?  How is the exhaust fan supposed to NOT leak air as much as a chimney with the flue open??

Comment: Fiberglass doesn't burn, but paper backing on fiberglass can, as well as cooking grease which the fiberglass might collect. Is there any way to seal the fan to the duct work a bit better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use your exhaust fan.  It removes grease, products of combustion and most of all moisture.  Do you just never use your stove top?  I suppose if all you ever do is microwave and use your oven you don't need to.

You can fill the gap with roxul insulation which is fire proof.

Typically your exhaust fan venting will lead to the exterior wall which has a wall cap.  The wall cap has a damper.  The damper usually seals somewhat against the wall cap to prevent drafts and only fully opens when the fan pushes air out causing the light metal flap to push outward.

Comment: It might be helpful to explain *why* you want to remove those things.  Most of my houses haven't had exhaust fans (no convenient place to vent), and it hasn't been a problem.

Comment: Also, those dampers are not very effective at preventing drafts.

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica - Thank you.  That's helpful.  I will write a separate question which I hope you'll contribute an answer to.

Comment: Thank you, Fresh.  I will consider this accepted and closed because of the type of insulation you suggested, but will write a separate question about the fan.

Answer (score 0):

I asked for the fireproof insulation at Lowe's and they said they have Rockwool but it only comes in large amounts.  They suggested the orange Great Stuff instead.  I am going to try that.  It is called "fireblock" insulating foam sealant.

---

Pretty happy with the results.